# Connection Error while communicating with Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to communicate with Instagram API, once i provide the details about Client ID and Client Secret and get authenticated, Instagram sends me back to given redirected URL where i am trying to retrieve the basic user info and recent photos but after waiting for a while, it gives me this error

*A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 179.60.192.52:443*

Please let me know if anybody faced and resolved this before.

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, it was due to the firewall policy of my network that was blocking few ports. Once i hosted my work with a professional hosting company, it worked like a charm. Thank you for the folks who took time to answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be that you didn't authorize with your account maybe? Go to the actual redirect URL in your browser and it might be an authorization URL.

I believe i had the same problem and had to write code to go to the actual URL and press the button to be able to use the API with my account.

even if i already had the client ID and Secret

Comment: Thank you for your reply mate.

However, i guess my question was not very clear. My application is having two pages, at first page, i click the button and call the instagram API by following code

Response.Redirect("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&response_type=code");

It takes me to the instagram login page, i provide my credentials to get authenticated.

once authenticated, it takes me to the given redirected URL where i have written the code to extract the basic information of student.

Error comes at this page.

Comment: Have you extracted the access token from the redirect URL?

it will be something like http://www.google.com/code=&token